# Paypal checkout form with custom values

Tags: php, html, paypal

let me explain my problem. First I am a total newbie in paypal transaction and I am finding extremely hard to navigate into paypal APIs. My customer asked me to create an online shop with paypal integration. As far as I could get, I understood that every item on the market has to have it's own paypal link but that seem strange to me. So the question here is, how can i create a form to a paypal payment? also how can I send the ammount of the transaction as well as the description (and eventually another value to recognise the transaction later on) to the paypal checkout page? Thank you very much and sorry if it seems a stupid question but it is getting extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start to familiarise yourself with PayPal and PHP would be here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK

Without seeing examples of what you've tried etc, it is difficult to guide you any further.